# Is there a better way to update Python so that it defaults to the newest version?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just decided to update from 3.6.5 to 3.7, I downloaded the installer and ran it. I went to test it in my terminal and typing "python" started 3.6.5. I then uninstalled 3.6.5, which in turn forced me to reinstall 3.7. Is there a way to update python so that everything automatically uses the new version?

Comment: " I then uninstalled 3.6.5, which in turn forced me to reinstall 3.7" This seems strange. Anyway, in general, you don't update an interpreter, you merely download the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no supported way to upgrade/downgrade a Python installation in place. You must download and install a new release.

Official releases are found on the [download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).